# Call cmd.exe command in Qt

Tags: qt, cmd

I need to trigger the following command

```
convert C:\test.pdf C:\test.jpg
```

from within my app.

I tried

```
QProcess proc;
QStringList args = QStringList();
args << "convert";
args << "C:\\test.pdf";
args << "C:\\test.jpg";
int i = proc.execute("cmd.exe",args);
```

It does not work. Why?

EDIT: Windows 7 32bit

EDIT2: To be more precise, replaced the \ with \\

Comment: No error message. My GUI freezes. If I type the command directly in the cmd, it finishes within less than a second. proc is of type 'QProcess' that is always suggested if I search for such a task.

Comment: execute() is a static method, it does nothing with proc. Create Qprocess on the heap or make it a class member and use start() if you want to run the command without blocking the UI

Answer (score 0):

You don't have much information but anyway I'll suggest a couple of things:

try to execute directly:

> cmd.exe convert C:\test.pdf C:\test.jpg

the above command is what you're trying to run from the code. If doesn't work, you should try changing your code to:

```
QProcess proc;
QStringList args = QStringList();
args << "C:\test.pdf";
args << "C:\test.jpg";
int i = proc.execute("convert",args); // Since you can run  "convert C:\test.pdf C:\test.jpg" 
                                      // I'm assuming you have convert.exe in your PATH environment variable.
```

Comment: Calling convert directly instead of cmd.exe should fix the permanent freeze. But note that execute() is a static method and will block the UI while convert runs. Use start() for non-blocking execution. then proc must survive the current method though

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double slash:

```
args << "C:\\test.pdf";
```

Or:

```
args << QDir::toNativeSeparators( "C:/test.pdf" );
```

Because `\t` is a one tab character. So your string became `C:    est.pdf`

Comment: you are right, it throws an error like "unknown command C: est". But \\ did not work as well, also `/` does not work.

Comment: well, but an obvious one that I knew to solve. The point is more how to call a command in general.